# Adding file-specific ACL to S3 upload using PHP SDK (1.6.2)

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, acl

I am using the AWS SDK 1.6.2 for PHP and want to be able to upload a file to a bucket, make it private by default, and then allow read access to certain IAM users.

I have created an IAM user "blah@test.com" and am calling the upload function as follows:

```
$response = $s3->create_object('my-bucket', 'filename.ext', array(
    'fileUpload' => '/path/to/local/file',
    'headers'    => array('Cache-Control' => 'max-age=0'),
    'acl'        => array(
        array('id' => 'blah@test.com', 'permission' => AmazonS3::GRANT_READ)
    ),
));
```

This adds the header `x-amz-grant-read:emailAddress="blah@test.com"` as expected, but when doing this I get an error in the response:

```
Code -> "UnresolvableGrantByEmailAddress"
Message -> "The e-mail address you provided does not match any account on record."
```

I have also tried using an IAM user with a non-email username and also using the full Amazon Resource Name (aRN, e.g. `arn:aws:iam::{account_no}:user/{username}`), in which cases I get the corresponding "Invalid ID" error.

Have I misunderstood something in the IAM/SDK docs, or am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Where you pass the ACL ID, it should be the actual Access Key ID for the IAM user.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I created an Access Key for the user using the IAM panel, and tried to supply the Access Key generated, but still get "InvalidArgument" => "Invalid id"

Comment: It should be the canonical account ID, not the access key ID.

Comment: Ack. Yes, that's what I meant to say.